# Kibana Bargraph not filtering data properly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I have inserted following dataset in index "testfilter"

```
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"testfilter"}}
{ "jobid": 1, "table_name": "table_A", "Tags": [ { "TagType": "WorkTypeA", "Tag": "ETL" }, { "TagType": "Subject Area", "Tag": "Telecom" } ] }
{"index":{"_index":"testfilter"}}
{ "jobid": 2, "table_name": "table_B", "Tags": [ { "TagType": "WorkTypeB", "Tag": "Engineering" }, { "TagType": "Subject Area", "Tag": "Telecom" } ] }
{"index":{"_index":"testfilter"}}
{ "jobid": 3, "table_name": "table_C", "Tags": [ { "TagType": "WorkTypeC", "Tag": "Development" }, { "TagType": "Subject Area", "Tag": "Telecom" } ] }
```

And the index mapping ( GET testfilter/_mapping )  is as follows

```
{
  "testfilter" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Tags" : {
          "properties" : {
            "Tag" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "TagType" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "jobid" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "table_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I create a bar graph visualization in Kibana by choosing X Axis as :

```
Aggregation : Terms
Filed : Tags.Tag.keyword
```

The graph gets build correctly. When I filter by choosing **Tag : Development**, I am getting ***two bar one filtering "Development" and other that of "Telecom"*** ( as seen in screenshot)
[image]

How do i build the graph that **when I filter on any Tag I should get only that Tag data**?

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the fact that you are **storing List of strings in field Tags.Tag** in this document. If this is the case, then elasticsearch is functioning correctly.

You need to understand how elasticsearch aggregation works. Let's suppose you have inserted below json in elasticsearch

```
{
  "Tags": {
    "tag": [
      "abc",
      "def"
    ]
  }
}
```

and in your visualization, you have clicked on term abc.

So elasticsearch on backend will fire a query and try to aggregate on all the terms present in all documents in which "abc" present in field "Tags.Tag.keyword".

So in your case, the document that has term development, might have also a value telecom in it, and so it showing this to you.

Comment: that is what I have tried to highlight but what exactly can be the solution ?

Comment: You can't do that. That's. how elasticsearch functions internally. It is a document-oriented search engine and gives you results on the basis of  document, now if you have added a list, it will show all elements of the list in the visualization. The max you can do is exclude terms manually that you don't want to see on visualization. Here is a link for the same. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4